# How to call several objects (data frame) in R so I only have to run a function once?

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, apply

I have several data frames in my environment, beginning with `SPECIALITY`:

[image: environment]

I would like to be able to only call the data frames once in my self-defined functions (possibly with an apply function), instead of having to run a line of code for each data frame like so:

[image: superfluous code]

I was thinking of combining the data frames into a list, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing this, or whether that would be the most efficient method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing them into a list is an excellent idea, you can do it this way:

```
new_list <- mget(ls(pattern="^SPECIALTY"))
```

And then use `lapply` on it with the function of your choice.

If you want to clean up your workspace after you've put them in a list, run :

```
rm(list = ls(pattern="^SPECIALTY")))
```

To go further you might want to challenge why you got them in separated tables to start with, maybe it's because you've done something like:

```
SPECIALTY2014_Q1 <- read.csv("SPECIALTY2014_Q1.csv")
SPECIALTY2014_Q2 <- read.csv("SPECIALTY2014_Q2.csv")
...
```

In this case you could have done the following to store everything in a list from the start:

```
lapply(paste0("SPECIALTY", c("2014_Q1", "2014_Q2"),".csv"), read.csv)
```